# Automatically synchronizing a Subversion repository and a Git repository

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, githooks, svn-hooks

My project has a Subversion repository on a network file system, and a new team would like to access it using Git, and be able to commit to it and get updates from it.

What I have in mind is to create a new bare `git-svn` clone of the Subversion repository on the same network file system, and make sure the two repositories are always up to date with respect to each other.

The way to do this is probably to add a post-commit hook for both Subversion and the new Git repository, that will each update the other's repository.

The Subversion post-commit hook will include `git svn rebase`, and the Git one `git svn dcommit`.

The problem is that I will have to use some kind of lock to make sure no one commits to either repository while other is also being committed to, because they always have to be in sync before any commit.  This has several disadvantages, among them the time it will take to commit to Subversion or to push to the Git repository (it has to wait for the hook to finish), and the fact that some users may not be able to run `git svn` (because it's not installed on their machine), which means they can't update the other repository when committing/pushing.

How can I solve these problems?  What will the Subversion and Git hooks look like?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I've come up with:

1. Create the `git-svn` repository if it doesn't exist already:

   ```
   git svn init --std-layout <svn_url> <git-svn_path>
   ```

   The `master` branch is created automatically to track the `trunk`.
2. To avoid name ambiguities with Subversion-tracking branches, make the original Subversion branches show as `remotes/svn/<branch name>`: go to the newly-created `git-svn` repository and run

   ```
   git config svn-remote.svn.fetch trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
   git config svn-remote.svn.branches branches/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
   git config svn-remote.svn.tags tags/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*

   rm .git/refs/remotes/*
   git svn fetch
   ```
3. Create a Subversion-tracking branch for each Subversion branch:

   ```
   for BRANCH in $(svn ls <svn_url>/branches/); do
       git branch $BRANCH remotes/svn/$BRANCH
   done
   ```
4. Make sure no non-Subversion-tracking branches are created on the central Git repository:

   ```
   # Used by hooks/update:
   git config hooks.denyCreateBranch true
   git config hooks.allowDeleteBranch false

   cp .git/hooks/update.sample .git/hooks/update
   chmod +x .git/hooks/update
   ```
5. Allow pushing to the central Git repository:

   ```
   git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
   git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true
   git config push.default current
   ```

   And create the post-receive hook to reset and send the commits to Subversion:

   ```
   cat .git/hooks/post-receive

       #!/bin/sh

       date >> receive.log
       git reset --quiet --hard
       while read LINE
       do
           BRANCH=${LINE##*/}
           echo Updating $BRANCH
           git checkout --quiet --force $BRANCH
           git svn dcommit
       done 2>&1 | tee -a receive.log
       git checkout --quiet --force master

   chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive
   ```

   The reset is necessary, because otherwise the current branch is out-of-date after each receive.
6. Finally, create the hook to get updates from Subversion:

   ```
   cat .git/hooks/svn-rebase-all

       #!/bin/sh

       date >> .git/svn-rebase.log
       git reset --quiet --hard
       for REF in .git/refs/heads/*
       do
           BRANCH=${REF##*/}
           echo Updating $BRANCH
           git checkout --quiet --force $BRANCH
           git svn rebase
       done 2>&1 | tee -a .git/svn-rebase.log
       git checkout --quiet --force master

   chmod +x .git/hooks/svn-rebase-all
   ```

   And call it from the Subversion post-commit hook:

   ```
   cat <svn_path>/hooks/post-commit

       cd <git_path>
       . .git/hooks/svn-rebase-all

   chmod +x <svn_path>/hooks/post-commit
   ```

Instead of using a single `git-svn` central repository, one can use a bare central Git repository and an intermediate non-bare `git-svn` repository, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014422/hooks-for-git-svn/2032889#2032889).
I chose to use one non-bare `git-svn` repository which is also the central repository.

Anyone can work on the project using Git by cloning `<git_path>` and pushing to it, or using Subversion by checking out `<svn_url>` and committing to it.

Comment: `git config hooks.denycreatebranch false`  
@Daniel did you mean "true"?

Comment: @basin Yes, I suppose so. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're better off with just having each developer learn to use `git-svn` directly.  There's simply too much of an impedance mismatch between the git and SVN models to be able to robustly implement what you are looking for.  The only way you could get it to work even nearly reliably would be to enact the same sort of restrictions that `git-svn` would have, but with more moving parts that could break.  In my opinion, your revision control system is not the sort of thing that you want to be just partially reliable.

Alternatively just ditch SVN altogether and move all the way to git, if possible.

Comment: I do plan to move my team to Git altogether at some point, but I thought the gradual move git-svn allows is a big advantage.  I guess the other team will have to make a complete copy of my git-svn clone, and use git svn dcommit and git svn rebase themselves.

Comment: If multiple git repos are using git-svn to push/pull from a central svn repo, which I believe is what's being recommended here, then it will be difficult to push/pull directly between those git repos.  This is because git branches are rebased during 'git svn rebase'.

Comment: That's right, and it also makes the transition to a pure Git configuration much harder in the future, because everyone will have to "migrate" their Git repositories by creating patches and applying them on newly-cloned repositories from a new central Git repository.