# How to update an SVN repository after a Git push?

Tags: git, svn

After migrating from SVN To Git the team is now using Git.
We are now pushing new code into the Git servers.

But in parallel I would like to keep the old SVN repository up to date (we have too many scripts and applications that are still using SVN)

How do I synchronized my new Git repository with my old SVN repository ?

If I understand correctly, you can easily do the opposite, meaning updating your new Git repository in case of new commit in your old SVN repository using git svn fletch command, but I would like to go to the other direction.

In another word, how do I commit my changes from the Git repository to the SVN repository ?

Thanks

Comment: How did you migrate? Did you clone the SVN repository into a git repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you have used git-svn to create your Git repo, then you can use a post-receive hook on yuor bare Git repo in order to trigger a `git-svn dcommit`.
You can see one at "[Automatically synchronizing a Subversion repository and a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7645450/6309)".

If not, you have to write a post-receive hook which would apply a git commit to the right svn checked out workspace. That isn't as easy as using `git-svn`.