# Is there a hook for git-svn that prevents from dcommit'ing branches?

Tags: git-svn

I need some way to prevent myself from accidentally dcommitting local branches - except for master branch, of course. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014422/hooks-for-git-svn help here?

Comment: isn't just dcommit following the global config rule that states that when you push it will sync all branches or only the current branch (depending on conf) ?

Comment: @v.oddou: No, it does not. dcommit does not use the configuration settings for `git push` (though one might argue that it should).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid an accidental dcommit from a local branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226528/how-can-i-avoid-an-accidental-dcommit-from-a-local-branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `git svn dcommit` in an alias and add some test there.

I'm using following alias in `.gitconfig`:

```ini
[alias]
    safe-dcommit = "!f() { if test \"$(git symbolic-ref HEAD)\" != refs/heads/master; then echo You must be on master branch; else git svn dcommit \"$@\"; fi; }; f"
    dc = !git safe-dcommit
```