# execute git commands on git push

Tags: git

Is there a way to execute couple of git commands when I `git push` to master?
What I'm having in mind is, once i did a `git push` for grunt to execute:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to execute the above steps using grunt? Are you on Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use Grunt to execute these commands? I think a normal shell script would suffice. Assuming you are on Linux, create an executable file called `post-receive` in the `.git/hooks` subdirectory, with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=$GIT_DIR/..
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git checkout master
```

For more information search [this page](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) for "post-receive hook".

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks), which would:

- go to a non-bare repo (meaning you need 2 repos on the server side: [one bare](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html), one non-bare)
- git pull from the same bare repo you just pushed to
- checkout, merge, checkout

You have an example in "[how do I deploy multiple branches to different directories via git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464252/6309)", but you need to complete that script an `unset GIT_DIR`, to be sure git takes into account the right non-bare repo after the `cd /path/to/non/bar/repo`.