# Git - deploy dist folder to different remote

Tags: git, deployment, git-remote, git-subtree

I'm trying to figure out a way to deploy a `dist` folder to a different remote repo using Git.

The working project is stored in an `app` folder. I use grunt to optimize and compile the working project into a `dist` folder. I want to know if there is a way I can than use git to push only the `dist` folder to a different remote than the origin that the rest of the project uses.

Obviously, I just need the dist folder to go live. Not the whole project.

I tried looking into Git Subtree - but I'm not sure that I'm understanding the concept or if I can use it to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Any advice would be extremely helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Rich

Answer (score 10):

You can:

- make dist as an independent repo within your current repo.
- [declare `dist` as a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18843515/6309): see [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-6.html).
- set a remote within the `dist` repo referencing your production server.

  ```
  git remote add prod /url/to/your/prod/server
  ```
- push from that submodule

  ```
  cd dist
  git push prod master
  ```

That supposes you have, on your server:

- setup a [**bare repo**](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html) `dist.git`
- put an [post-receive hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) which will, on receiving the push, go to the actual dist folder, and checkout the content of what you just pushed.
  See an example at "[how do I deploy multiple branches to different directories via git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1464252/6309)"

Answer (score 6):

If `dist` is also being revisioned by your repository you can also use subtree for your needs.

Assuming you already have a remote repository setup in your local repository, 
after you have committed your changes to `dist` the command for a subtree push would be:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist distRemote remoteBranch
```

What this command is doing is first creating a new set of commits in which `dist` is the root folder and only changes to `dist` appear. This commit is then pushed to the `remoteBranch` in the `distRemote` repository.